# Why can I not publish npm module to Google Artifact Registry?

Tags: npm, gcloud, google-artifact-registry

I run

`npx google-artifactregistry-auth --verbose`

And I seem to log in properly...

> Retrieving application default credentials...
> Success!

So now I try to deploy and get...

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://us-central1-npm.pkg.dev/my-proj/npm-public/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

I have set the `roles/artifactregistry.writer` role on the IAM service account used to generate the key file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry info had to be in `$WORKING_DIR/.npmrc` not `~/.npmrc`.

Once I ran `gcloud beta artifacts print-settings npm --repository=npm-public --location=us-central1 > .npmrc` and then re-ran `npx google-artifactregistry-auth` I could publish. I tried using `~/.npmrc` for the `--repo-config` but it still did not work

Comment: adding `npm config set @SCOPE_NAME:registry https://LOCATION-npm.pkg.dev/PROJECT/REPOSITORY/`
fixed the npm publish error